# Magmi product_primary_category column not importing

Tags: csv, magento, magmi

We have been using Magmi to import new products to our Magento install for a while now and have always set the column product_primary_category as Root Catalog -> Category -> Sub-Category

For some reason, recently the Product Primary Category no longer sets inside Magento and remains set on the default, "Please select primary category". We have tried changing the CSV column product_primary_category from Root Catalog -> Category -> Sub-Category to the actual ID of the category as well to no avail.

Has anyone experienced this? What was your fix? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So it worked for a while, then at some point is just stopped working? Did you upgrade Magento, Magmi or change the format of the input data at any point?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try using header `category_ids` with category ids instead. See

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t03ez.png)

Comment: We have category_ids set but it doesn't have any affect on the product_primary_category. Thanks for the suggestion though